# No Sound when i start Ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

i have ubuntu 14.04. After login my audio is disabled and it gets enabled only when i do

```
pkill -f jackd
```

what should i do to turn on audio by default in startup

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can search for the "startup applications" app, click "add" and name it "soundon" or whatever you want and place the command

```
pkill -f jackd
```

in the command box. You can leave comment blank it doesn't matter what you put here. The command should run automatically next time you login and sound should work.